# Picasso - can't find "context"

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, picasso, android-context

First of all,  I am a beginner and this may be a stupid question for you. **I need to pass context to the following code in order to load an image in the recyclerview.** Tried several options but any of them is not a success. My problem is how to find the context that to pass in the following code.

```
Picasso.with(context here).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(thumbnail);
```

Here is the full code which causes the problem(I am trying to pass an image to an recyclerview)

```
public class WishListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WishListAdapter.DerpHolder> {

    private List<WishListItem> listData;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public WishListAdapter(List<WishListItem> listData, Context c) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        this.listData = listData;
    }

    @Override
    public WishListAdapter.DerpHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wish_list_item, parent, false);
        return new DerpHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DerpHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    public void setListData(ArrayList<WishListItem> exerciseList) {
        this.listData.clear();
        this.listData.addAll(exerciseList);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    class DerpHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        ImageView thumbnail;
        TextView title;
        TextView subTitle;
        View container;


        public DerpHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.im_item_icon);

            //subTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_item_sub_title);

            //title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_item_text);

            container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cont_item_root);
            container.setOnClickListener(this);
            Picasso.with(context ).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(thumbnail);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("janitha", "item clicked");

        }
```

Also I have read following too:-[Picasso and context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928019/picasso-and-context)

Expect help from somebody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't saved context from your constructor. Do as like as this:

```
public class WishListAdapter extends 
     RecyclerView.Adapter<WishListAdapter.DerpHolder> {

    private List<WishListItem> listData;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;

    public WishListAdapter(List<WishListItem> listData, Context c) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        this.listData = listData;
        this.context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public WishListAdapter.DerpHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wish_list_item, parent, false);
        return new DerpHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DerpHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    public void setListData(ArrayList<WishListItem> exerciseList) {
        this.listData.clear();
        this.listData.addAll(exerciseList);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    class DerpHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        ImageView thumbnail;
        TextView title;
        TextView subTitle;
        View container;


        public DerpHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.im_item_icon);

            //subTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_item_sub_title);

            //title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_item_text);

            container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cont_item_root);
            container.setOnClickListener(this);
            Picasso.with(context ).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(thumbnail);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("janitha", "item clicked");

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
private Context context;
```

and in your constructor,

```
this.context = c;
```

now you can use 'context' as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code as following:

```
private List<WishListItem> listData;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context mContext;

public WishListAdapter(List<WishListItem> listData, Context c) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    this.listData = listData;
    this.mContext = c;
}
```

Then use `mContext` with **Picasso**:

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(thumbnail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please declare context variable like below and use it :

```
public class WishListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WishListAdapter.DerpHolder> {

    private List<WishListItem> listData;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context

    public WishListAdapter(List<WishListItem> listData, Context c) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        this.listData = listData;
        this.context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public WishListAdapter.DerpHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wish_list_item, parent, false);
        return new DerpHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DerpHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    public void setListData(ArrayList<WishListItem> exerciseList) {
        this.listData.clear();
        this.listData.addAll(exerciseList);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    class DerpHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        ImageView thumbnail;
        TextView title;
        TextView subTitle;
        View container;


        public DerpHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.im_item_icon);

            //subTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_item_sub_title);

            //title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_item_text);

            container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cont_item_root);
            container.setOnClickListener(this);
            Picasso.with(context ).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(thumbnail);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("janitha", "item clicked");

        }
```